# Expo, React Native takePictureAsync does not return

Tags: react-native, android-camera, expo

I'm using `expo-camera` pretty much straight from the code snippet in the [docs](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/camera/) and the `takePictureAsync` function never returns.

```
  async takePicture () {
    try {
      let photo = await this.camera.takePictureAsync()
      console.log('this will never return', photo)
    } catch (err) {
      console.error('this does not error', err)
    }
  }
```

I have granted permission and I've tested out various ways it might be a promise issue, but no luck.

I'm running on-device with a Pixel 3a. Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: It accepts an options object as an argument, have you tried that?  And make sure the apps cache is large enough for the photo.

Comment: Heh, looks like the options object is required and does not error if you omit it. Looks like all I had to do is pass an empty object.

Comment: Mind if I put it in an answer

Comment: I had the same issue except only on the android emulator. Everything works fine on a physical device. If anyone is encountering the same issue see my answer here: https://github.com/react-native-camera/react-native-camera/issues/3141#issuecomment-1525911195

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It accepts an options object as a a required argument.

> quality (number) -- Specify the quality of compression, from 0 to 1. 0
>   means compress for small size, 1 means compress for maximum quality.
>
> exif (boolean) -- Whether to also include the EXIF data for the image.
>
> onPictureSaved (function) -- A callback invoked when picture is saved.
>   If set, the promise of this method will resolve immediately with no
>   data after picture is captured. The data that it should contain will
>   be passed to this callback. If displaying or processing a captured
>   photo right after taking it is not your case, this callback lets you
>   skip waiting for it to be saved.
>
> skipProcessing (boolean) - Android only. If set to true, camera skips
>   orientation adjustment and returns an image straight from the device's
>   camera. If enabled, quality option is discarded (processing pipeline
>   is skipped as a whole). Although enabling this option reduces image
>   delivery time significantly, it may cause the image to appear in a
>   wrong orientation in the Image component (at the time of writing, it
>   does not respect EXIF orientation of the images).

[source](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/camera/)

Comment: Would be nice if it threw an error if you don't include it!

Comment: It would once this is all in typescript. They're not done yet though and I'm not sure if this is part of it. https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/guides/typescript/

Comment: I should note that this sometimes doesn't work with just an empty object. The only way I've gotten it to consistently work is with the `skipProcessing: true` option.